# Clear selected value and list

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-select

Using the [**React-Select library**](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select), to create a selector for the `onChange` event. So whenever I select a **Region** the **Cities** list should update, however, the first city selected remains selected when I change the Region ...

After changing the state, the list of cities is updated, however, the selected city remains selected, I would like to clean it up. the variable that defines the value of the variable is updated but does not change the component.

[in the text is updated, nulled, and but in the form it continues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYgDF.png)

I want to know how to remove the selected option when I change the region.

This is [the code-sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactcodesandboxerexample-04dxp) I'm using

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on the question ? Sandbox does not have any clue what are you trying say :confused:.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to make it clearer. but I do not know how to express myself if I can analyze the code thanks.

Comment: Why don't you only fetch the data on selection ? Do you need to keep the state of the each selection ? Probably you can push to the selected array if you want to keep track of the selection.

Comment: searching the data this way I think that faster, more thanks for idea

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your goal you need to update your code at two places:

1. In `fetchCidades` function:

You will need to add `cidadeOrigem: null` in all the `setState`like this:

```
async fetchCidadesO() {

    if (this.state.estadoOrigem) {
      let body = {};
      body.estado = this.state.estadoOrigem.value;
      let URL = "https://fretesbrasil.herokuapp.com/api/cidadeo";
      if (stringify(body) !== "") URL += `?${stringify(body)}`;
      //console.log(URL);

      const data = await fetch(URL)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch(error => this.setState({ error }));

      this.setState({
        // ({value: '', label: 'Todos'}
        cidadeOrigem: false,
        cidadesO: data.data.map(cidade => ({
          value: cidade,
          label: cidade
        }))
      });
    } else
      this.setState({
        // ({value: '', label: 'Todos'}
        cidadeOrigem: false,
        cidadesO: []
      });
  }
```

2. In your `Select` itself:

Using `value={cidadeOrigem}` instead of `value={this.cidadeOrigem}`

```
<Select
   className="basic-single"
   placeholder="Cidade de Origem"
   onChange={this.toggleCidadeO} //{value => this.setState({ value })}
   //defaultValue={cidadesO[0]}
   value={cidadeOrigem}
   name="cidadeOrigem"
   //isDisabled={this.cidadeODisable} don't work
   isSearchable={true}
   options={cidadesO}
/>
```

I have cleaned your code here and enabled the `disabled` props that you commented as `not working` so you can test live [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-answer-56212768-hrn91).